# How to create and edit fonts for the Adafruit GFX library?

Tags: adafruit, tft

I noticed that the `TomThumb.h` font included in the Adafruit GFX library has characters that have different widths, which is a problem for me because I'm doing text processing that requires characters to have the same dimensions (width and height).

I also noticed that the `TomThumb.h` font misses some characters (such as `'`). I need a way to create/edit fonts for the Adafruit GFX (where I'm using the Adafruit_ST7735 on a 1.8" TFT display). I've looked around the internet but I couldn't find anything decent.

Comment: The library comes with a number of fonts. The ones named `*Mono*` are monospaced, which means that all the characters are the same size.

Comment: @Majenko Interesting. I thought that by default all characters are required to take equal dimensions.

Comment: Nope. Each character in the font ("glyph") specifies the dimensions and offset of the character, and also the "advance" - how far to move the cursor after printing the character.

Comment: @Majenko I'm surprised there isn't an easy way to create fonts for the Adafruit GFX. It's a relatively supported and used library.

Comment: I have various utilities for DisplayCore, but DisplayCore doesn't run on an Arduino.

Comment: @Majenko My main goal here is to display text of a book. Is there any way I can do that without using a monospaced font? Because I'm preprocessing the text on a phone and I'm doing the whole thing by counting how many characters a line can fit and so on so when a word doesn't fit, it goes to the next line... you get the idea. Is it possible to make the whole when-word-doesn't-fit-goes-on-next-line and with page switching functionality using a non-monospaced font? I suppose I'll have to know how many pixels each character takes so I do calculations...

Comment: Split your text into words and use the getTextBounds function to find out how wide it is. Add the width of a space. If it fits on the current line then print it. Otherwise start a new line and print it. You'll have to maintain your own cursor coordinates of course.

Comment: @Majenko Sound great! What do you mean about the cursor coordinates?

Comment: So that you know where to print your next word.

Comment: @Majenko Oh got it. The getTextBounds() requires the starting x and y of the word. Ahh, it's gonna be rather painful but I have no other option. Thank you for helping me out! :-)

Comment: @Majenko About the page functionality, do you have an idea of how it can be done? I'm reading the book content from an SD. The issue I have with the paging functionality is that if I'm on page 82, I have to process all pages until 82 and it's starting to lag as I get further into the book. I'm ready to drop the pages as a whole but I need some way to return the person to the place in the book from where he/she left, so he/she can continue reading. What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: @Majenko After researching a bit, I think I can do it with fseek and remembering the last character of the last word... Thank you so much for helping me and suggesting the method above. You're the best!

Comment: @Majenko One thing that's unclear is, how would I go about going to previous pages? If I'm on some page and I've processed it and displayed it, how do I go to the previous page not knowing from which character to seek and so on...?

Comment: That is a tough one to suggest a solution to. Maybe plain text isn't the best format to store the data in.

Comment: @Majenko Hmm, I'm converting PDF to text and sending that from a phone to the Arduino via BT and then I'm displaying the text on a 1.8" TFT display. What else could I store it as when my goal is to make something like an e-reader?

Comment: Maybe render the pages on the phone as bitmap images and display those on the screen instead?

Comment: @Majenko Good suggestion but the text might not be visible or readable because the TFT display is rather small (1.8") and is 128x160 pixels and I don't think the content of the PDF page would be visible :P

Comment: I'm not thinking pages as they are on a PDF, but pre-rendered in your own chosen font.

Comment: @Majenko Yes but the issue of characters of fonts having different widths persists. As far as understood, on the phone, I create a bitmap image 128x160 where I overlay the text with the chosen font but I'll still have to do the same text processing as if it was being processed on the Arduino as text. It gets really complicated so I think I'll process the txt on the Arduino with the method you suggested above with getTextBounds...

Comment: @Majenko The idea of doing it with bitmap images is good but comparing pros and cos with the on-the-go processing with getTextBounds(), the latter is better because it allows for dynamic font changing, is less complicated and less heavy (because text files are lighter than bitmap images of pages). And also uploading speeds would be much much faster. Tell me what you think :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found an online editor that can parse Adafruit GFX font headers, modify, and export the result to create a new font header.  It works very well.  May be a bit late to help OP, but for anyone else looking...

It uses regexes to extract info from the header files, so it's pretty strict on following the layout of GFX font headers provided by Adafruit.

webpage: https://tchapi.github.io/Adafruit-GFX-Font-Customiser/
github: https://github.com/tchapi/Adafruit-GFX-Font-Customiser

Comment: That works nicely, once you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution you might already have: There’s a small utility called `fontconvert` that’s part of the Adafruit GFX library. The source code is installed by default together with the Adafruit GFX library in `Arduino/libraries/Adafruit_GFX_Library/fontconvert` You need Linux to compile it from the provided source code. It also compiles and runs on a Raspberry Pi.

It takes care of converting TrueType fonts (completely or partially) to Adafruit GFX format. There’s some documentation on compiling and using it in the fontconvert directory.

Comment: Thanks, I found it. Unfortunately, I don't have a Linux nor a Raspberry Pi. I could install a Linux VM. Isn't there an easier way? Like, some tool where you put the individual pixels for each character.

Comment: Well, there’s [This](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=447956.0). I don’t know how useful this is for you, but you could take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I hope it'll do the job

Answer (score 0):

I have used this website to generate various fonts, sizes, etc. with success.

http://oleddisplay.squix.ch/#/home

Answer (score 0):

I have used [truetype2gfx - Converting fonts from TrueType to Adafruit GFX](https://rop.nl/truetype2gfx/).

It can make various sizes to a complete standard font.

Comment: @ocrdu - did you visit the website and try out the "tool"? How did it work for you?